# Python - ping in for loop

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, networking

I try to ping through for loop , the problem it's done only to the last number
in this case the ping done only to the x.x.x.4 address

```
import subprocess
import socket

ipl = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4 = ipl.split(".")
stip = seg1 + "." + seg2 + "." + seg3 + "."

i = 0
for i in range(1,5):
    cmd = "ping -n 1 " + stip + str(i)
    print(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout) = p.communicate()
    fiw = open("1.txt", 'w')
    fiw.write(str(stdout))
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: You're opening `1.txt` in `w` mode, meaning it is created fresh each time through the loop.  The file will end up with only the results of the final command.

Comment: My bad changed it to `'+a'` instead of `'w'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fiw = open("1.txt",'w')
for i in range(1,5):
    cmd = "ping -n 1 " + stip + str(i)
    print(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout) = p.communicate()
    fiw.write(str(stdout))
fiw.close()
```

Try to change your code

Comment: The file needs to be in binary mode, e.g. `fiw = open('1.txt', 'wb')`,  and you need to get just the standard output from the tuple, e.g. `stdout, stderr = p.communicate()`, and write it as `fiw.write(stdout)`. (If the file is in text mode, then `stdout` needs to be decoded; `str` is just the repr of a `bytes` object.) But since you're just writing the output directly to the file, I suggest skipping the pipe, e.g. `subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=fiw)`.

Comment: Outputing into a text file is one of the functions i want 2 pipe the ips which responded with UP any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

changed the `fiw = open("1.txt", 'w')` to `fiw = open("1.txt", '+a')`

```
import subprocess
import socket

ipl = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
seg1, seg2, seg3, seg4 = ipl.split(".")
stip = seg1 + "." + seg2 + "." + seg3 + "."

i = 0
for i in range(1,5):
    cmd = "ping -n 1 " + stip + str(i)
    print(cmd)
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    (stdout) = p.communicate()
    fiw = open("1.txt", 'w')
    fiw.write(str(stdout))
```

Outputing into a text file is one of the functions i want 2 pipe the ips which responded with UP